# Alternatives to a windows service for polling application

Tags: .net, windows-services

I have a C# program that needs to query a database table and make a call to a webservice on a polling interval.

I know I could wrap this up as a windows service. However I am wondering if there are any other tools and techniques where I could call my exe on a schedule without having to create a service.

Answer (score 0):

- You can schedule your program to run using Scheduled Tasks (`taskschd.msc`), which is basically the Windows version of `cron`.
- You could also have your program run on startup and sit in the tray, sleeping while it waits for its own timer to expire.